# Route to cross matrix gathering a maximum sum

Tags: algorithm

So I've stumbled upon an interesting problem while I was shifting through a book.
You are given an N*M matrix and you have to get from coordinate (1,1) to (n,m).

You are given three types of "operations" to cross the matrix with.

```
'A'- You go from i,j to i+1,j

'B'- You go from i,j to i,j+1

'C'- You go from i,j to i+1,j+1
```

Every time you cross an element, you add it to your "sum". You are asked to:

1. Find the maximum sum you can gather.
2. Reconstruct the route without using/re-using a N*M matrix.

I had no problem solving (1) with dynamic programming, but (2) put me in quite a pickle. The book doesn't have any explanation for point (2). Was wondering if any of you encountered something similar before.

Comment: What does econstruct the rout mean more exactly? A series of A, B & C?

Comment: You can reduce the problem to a shortest path problem in a DAG (which by definition has no negative cycles) and simply use Bellman-Ford Algorithm to find shortest path on `-1*X` (`X` is your matrix).

Comment: @Mihai Bratulescu Reconstruction the route means printing the series of movements you made to get from (1,1) to (n,m)

Comment: @amit Belman-Ford is also dynamic programming approach. It is just a popular one. I am not saying your comment is wrong, but I am just saying OP may be using it(without ever realizing). Recovering the solution with Bellman-Ford is just as hard as with any other DP I believe(and not that hard at all IMHO).

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev that's why it is a comment and not an answer. It gives a different view on the problem and might help the OP, but it does not answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

A general rule of thumb for DP: if you need to reconstruct the optimal solution in addition to getting the optimal value, use a second array. This second array should be of exactly the same size as the one where you store the answers for the subproblems. In this array, however, instead of storing the answer you store some identification of the subproblem that led to the optimal solution. In your case the identification would be `A`, `B` or `C` to indicate which move you've made.

Answer (score 0):

You can reconstruct the path itself using only the array of subproblem solutions (let's call it `D`), without any additional arrays. Just go from the `(n, m)` to `(1, 1)` backwards using the following rule:

- If `D[i][j] == D[i - 1][j]`, add `(i-1, j)` to the beginning of the answer sequence
- If `D[i][j] == D[i][j - 1]`, add `(i, j - 1)` to the beginning of the answer sequence
- Else add (i - 1, j - 1) to the beginning of the answer sequence.

You can easily prove (having in mind that
`D[i][j] = M[i][j] + max(D[i - 1][j], D[i][j - 1], D[i - 1][j - 1])`,
 where `M` is the initial matrix) that this will lead you to (1, 1), and that the resulting sequence is the maximum sum path indeed.